# Can I save a rectangle created using a canvas context?

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I created a lot of squares using a context from a canvas element I have in an HTML page.

```
    var c = document.getElementById("LineCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    for(let i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        for(let j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            ctx.fillRect(i * 35, j * 35, 15, 5);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to save these rectangles in some sort of array so I can access them in the future? specifically I need to rotate them.

Comment: Store the data you need into Objects that you can use to recreate shapes when you use those properties in a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use an array of an object that contains all the details of the rectangle (x,y,w,h) thanks for the answers

Answer (score -1):

Add them to an array as they are created:

```
var array = [];
  var c = document.getElementById("LineCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    for(let i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        for(let j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
           array.push(ctx.fillRect(i * 35, j * 35, 15, 5));
        }
    }
```

Comment: ctx.fillRect() doesn't return anything, hence why I cannot do that.

Comment: Use a rectangle or shape object, you will need to research the syntax for creating a new shape, adding it to the canvas, then setting the fill.